# How do i correctly implement a style trigger to fire when a ListView finishes populating?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, datatrigger

I want to set up the style of my `ListView` so that appearance will change once it has been populated. I found that there is this thing called an `ItemContainerGenerator` within the `ListView` that contains a `Status` property that will be set to `ContainersGenerated` once this is finished ( I think ).

So in order to accomplish this goal, I figured the best way would be to define a style data trigger to fire on that property.

But it's not working ( of course ). What I am seeing is the following error in the output -

`System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Status' value (type 'GeneratorStatus') from '' (type 'ListView'). BindingExpression:Path=(ItemContainerGenerator.Status); DataItem='ListView' (Name=''); target element is 'ListView' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object') TargetException:'System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(Object item, Int32 level)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Int32 k)'`

In compliance with the [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirements when asking a question -

1. Create a new project in Visual Studio titled 'MCVE'.
2. Copy and paste the below code over the MainWindow.xaml code.
3. Run Program. Get Data Error. Silently Weep.

   `<Window
       x:Class="MCVE.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MCVE"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
       <ListView>
           <ListView.Style>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                   <Style.Triggers>
                       <DataTrigger
                           Binding="{Binding 
                               (ItemContainerGenerator.Status),
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                           Value="{x:Static GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated}">
                           <!-- This is where I'd put my setters - IF THE TRIGGER WORKED!!! -->
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                       </DataTrigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
           </ListView.Style>
           <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
               </Style>
           </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
           <ListView.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Rows="1" />
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemsPanel>
           <ListViewItem>Foo</ListViewItem>
           <ListViewItem>Bar</ListViewItem>
           <ListViewItem>Baz</ListViewItem>
       </ListView>
   </Window>`

(Unfortunately because it's all in XAML, I have to wrap the entire code block in ` to get it to display)

So how can I properly create a Data Trigger that will fire when the `ListView` finishes populating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parentheses around ItemContainerGenerator.Status. Works for me. Btw, if you are using recycling, you'll switch statuses constantly when you scroll. Sounds like you should be using recycling and virtualization if your list is taking that long to populate. With a "normal" amount of items, the user will not even see the non completed state because it will happen instantly.